# Get Receiver Type and Method name from just a reference of function in Go

Tags: go

Given a code setup like this,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "runtime/debug"
)

type A struct{}

func (o *A) B() error {
    debug.PrintStack()
    return nil
}

func main() {
    a := &A{}
    b := a.B

    // Note that if run b(), it can print the stack and show the info 
    // "(*A).B-fm" and "(*A).B"

    m := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    fmt.Println(m.Type().String())
}
```

Is it possible to get the information of **b**'s receiver type A and B as a method? How if possible?

Note that **b** is value of method B of type A.

(Possible use scenario, generating a constant unique API ID based on only a reference like b, by forming a string like **(*A).B**. It's used to build a debug tool without a need to change existing code.)

update:

Comment: No you cannot. Sorry.

Comment: You can use:
```v := reflect.ValueOf(a)
m := v.MethodByName("B")```
But to get A type from B is impossible, but from you example you can just access a by doing `reflect.ValueOf(a)`

Comment: ah I only have access to "b". still learning.. maybe it's impossible. thanks for replies.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the work.

```
fmt.Println(runtime.FuncForPC(m.Pointer()).Name())
```

Credits to this [awesome article](http://www.alangpierce.com/blog/2016/03/17/adventures-in-go-accessing-unexported-functions/),